# Use socket.io in expressjs routes instead of in bin/www

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am using socket.io in expressJS

I have socket connection in bin/www

I would like to make , when I send data to sendmessage.js , I would like to send data to client side with socket.emit() in sendmessage.js

bin/www

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  pingInterval: 10000,
  pingTimeout: 5000,
}).listen(server)

io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('messageData', function(msg){

  io.sockets.emit('messageData', msg);
});
 socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){
 console.log("User DisConnected"); 
});
});
```

routers/sendmessage.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth');
var connection  = require('./db');

/* GET users listing. */
router.post('/', checkAuth , function(req, res, next) {
    res.send();  

});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem in concept of socket. When one socket connect, create a connection between client and socket.io server and keep connect. When you post a request to http server, another connection create between your client and http server. Connections are different and you can't emit data without accessing to socket.io connected socket.

Comment: I would like to make , when I send data to sendmessage.js , I would like to send data to client side with socket.emit() in sendmessage.js